# Double integral error Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

[image]I have a problem with computing a double integral. My code so far is:

```
B = 5; 
L0 = 0:10;
A0 = 0:10;
tau = 1:100;

% Open and read the file
fid = fopen('first.txt', 'r'); 
data = cell2mat(textscan(fid, '%d'));
data = dlmread('first.txt');

% Two columns in the file
% First corresponds to time
t = data(:,1); 
% Second to data values for luminosity
d = data(:,2); 

% Posteriors for the three models 0,1&2
p0 = ((1./sqrt(2.*pi))^10).*(exp(-sum(0.5.*(d-B).^2))); 
p1 =@(L0)((1./sqrt(2.*pi))^10).*(exp(-sum(0.5.*(d-B-L0).^2))); 
p2 = @(A0,tau)((1./sqrt(2.*pi))^10).*(exp(-sum(0.5.*(d-B-A0.*exp(-t/tau)).^2))); 

I1 = integral (p1, 0,10);
I2 = integral2 (p2,0, 10, 1, 100);

fclose(fid);
```

It seems to work fine for the normal integral I1 but crashes for the double integral I2. Any suggestions?
ps. Sorry for the long equations

ps2. I use Octave instead of Matlab, so dblquad means integral2 essentially.

in the file, I have this:

```
0 7.108842
1 5.360705
2 5.871565
3 4.441087
4 6.877640
5 6.049399
6 5.587317
7 6.687828
8 7.390521
9 5.646180
```

Comment: Any errors? What is content of first.txt?

Comment: In the file, I have two columns with numbers, one of them is d in the code, the other one t. I have added a pic with the errors.

Comment: Example of the text file would also be useful. Without this, cant reproduce your error.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I included it in the initial description now.

Comment: When you calcualte `p1`, d and B are vertical vectors, while L0 is horizontal one. This results in error. So this is one immediete problem I've noticed and maybe core of your issue.

Comment: Ho do I change that? And also, it gives me an answer for the integral of p1, so the issue is rather p2.

Comment: `p1` gives you anwser because you just declare it as a anon function. It reults in error when you acctually try to execute it in your in ingegral function. At least when I try it. Maybe your code and text file are different than you posted here?

Comment: No, everything is exactly the same. So, what should I do?

Comment: I dont know unfortunatley. Maybe some else here will have better idea and can help.

Comment: I found it. :) Apparently we can't define the integral as I1, I2 . When I changed that to another letter (q1, q2), it worked. I think it's something to do with I1 already used in the predefined integral functioned.